# Image in list item effects position of other text in other list items

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have an unnumbered list i am trying to format for a menu.

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="greatImage.png"></li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to have all the list items content vertically centered with each other. When i add the image to the first list item it looks as though all the other list items position is pushed to the bottom border of the UL block? Basically the image is effecting the rest of the list items position.

Comment: Can you show us the problem using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: This is the correct default appearance for list items. Are you asking for item 2 and item 3 to appear horizontally to the right of image and center vertically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is to set the line-height of the li equal to that of the image's height

example: http://jsfiddle.net/felcom/vdPtj/